# Придаточная часть из местоимения с предлогом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги, придаточное-предложение

Представим себе диалог:

*— Слушай, я не у вас пробовал вкуснейшие испанские оливки?

— Нет, не у нас.

— Жалко, хотелось бы понять, у кого. Расспросил бы поподробнее про них.*

Правильно я поставил запятую перед *"у кого"?* Перед придаточной частью, состоящей из одного союзного слова, запятую, как [известно](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137), не ставят, но правильно я рассудил, что с появлением предлога она уже ставится?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень интересный вопрос. Я раньше не обращал внимания на приводимые Розенталем уточнения относительно добавленной к союзному слову частицы (возможно, они не во всех изданиях присутствуют). На предлоги его уточнения не распространяются, но некоторый свет проливают и на данный вопрос. Вот их текст:

> Если при союзном слове, образующем придаточную часть, имеется частица,
> то постановка запятой перед ней факультативна: *Я не помню, **что именно**;*
> *Он затрудняется сказать, что ещё; Эту цитату можно будет найти, я даже*
> *помню **примерно где**.*

Факультативность я здесь понимаю не как возможность авторского решения, а  в том смысле, что в одних случаях запятая нужна (*"примерно где"* — видимо, здесь порядок двух слов решает), а в других — нет (*"что именно"*). При всей "скромности" понятия частицы, она способна придать словосочетанию заметную распространенность, которая, однако, не всегда приводит к запятой. Из уточнений Розенталя следует, что и в случае предлога *неизбежности* появления запятой быть не должно. Прямых дополнений к его параграфу мне нигде не встречалось, но в отношении предлога можно рассуждать так: если в качестве союзного слова выступает местоимение, падежи которого не влияют на появление запятой (таких оговорок нет), то что изменяет предлог, кроме **падежа**? Мне это видится менее сильной модификацией, чем добавляемый некоторыми частицами смысловой оттенок. Поэтому напрашивается вывод, что запятая нужна только в случаях контекстного (авторского) акцентирования, оговоренных для единственного союзного слова в том же параграфе (когда возможно и тире). Само же появление *предлога* к ней **не** приводит.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, рад, что вопрос понравился! Да, я на всякий случай предположил, что запятая нужна с предлогом, хотя подсознательно чувствовал, что это мелочь, причём и правда большая, чем частица. Про них тоже впервые прочитал, было очень интересно. Факультативность понял как раз как возможность авторского решения, но вполне верю вам, что на самом деле речь идёт о разных случаях (спасибо, что обратили на это внимание и растолковали).

Answer (score 3):

В справочнике [**Лопатина**](https://orfhographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=384) тоже не приводятся примеры с предлогами и делается акцент на **одном** союзном слове: «...одиночно употребленное союзное слово теряет функцию придаточного предложения...»

Здесь не приветствуются ответы типа "мне кажется" и т. п., но я рассуждаю следующим образом. Предлог (хоть и является ещё одним словом) — служебная часть речи, которая только ставит союзное слово (местоимение, существительное) в нужный падеж и не добавляет дополнительных членов предложения, чтобы образовалось полноценное придаточное.

*Жалко, хотелось бы понять кто* [мне дал попробовать].
*Жалко, хотелось бы понять у кого* [я мог пробовать].

**Примеры** из Нацкорпуса **без запятой**:

*Эта зима получилась (**не знаю у кого**) особенно холодная.* [Иржи Грошек. Легкий завтрак в тени некрополя (1998)]

*И не ради себя, нет, ради него я вдруг потребовала ― сама **не знаю у кого**, у судьбы, — чтобы дверь распахнулась...* [В. А. Каверин. Открытая книга (1949-1956)]

*Одно только охота спросить, и даже **не знаю у кого**: почему к нам исчужа рабочие не ездят?* [Владимир Чивилихин. Про Клаву Иванову (1964)]

*Слава участницы челюскинской экспедиции позволила Ольге Николаевне вымолить — **не знаю у кого** ― замену лагеря ссылкой.* [Р. М. Фрумкина. О нас – наискосок (1995)]

*Какие-нибудь уроки взять, правда **не знаю у кого**.* [ Красота, здоровье, отдых: Косметика и парфюм (форум) (2004)]

*Русской словесности ― что бог даст ― стану покупать, хоть и **не знаю у кого**?* [Н. А. Полевой. Письма (1824-1845)]

**С запятой**:

― Нет. **Не скажу, у кого**. У очень большого человека. [Захар Прилепин. Санькя (2006)]

*У кого? **Не знаю, у кого**. В квартире двадцать семь. Разрешите, я расскажу, как дело было...*  [А. И. Пантелеев. Ленька Пантелеев (1938-1952)]

*— Как ты думаешь, у кого он купит?

― Кажется, **я знаю, у кого**.* [Артем Лисицкий. Этика взятки // «Новая газета», 2003.01.23]

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Мне нравится эта логика — такая же, как у другого Александра.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Спасибо! Мне тоже вопрос понравился. Никогда бы, наверно, не обратил на это внимания.

Comment: А я вчера хотел спросить, ещё подумал, что стоит того, но отвлёкся и вечером вспомнил, что был какой-то вопрос, и только сегодня вспомнил, какой именно.