# Знаки препинания в предложении "Я болен, но только не знаю(,) чем"

Tags: пунктуация

В данном предложении придаточная часть из одного слова "чем" очень сильно усечена, поэтому возникает вопрос: ставим ли мы запятую? Мне лично кажется, что не ставим: сразу вспоминается фраза "принеси то, не знаю что, поди туда, не знаю куда". Вроде бы тут такая же ситуация, разве нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё правильно вам кажется. [Розенталь, § 33](https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=137):

> **4.** Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая ***не ставится:***
> <...>
> **3)** если **придаточная часть** состоит из **одного союзного слова** (относительного местоимения или наречия): *Я бы тоже желал знать **почему** (Л. Т.); Не знаю **почему,** но я его не понимал (Триф.); Трудно сказать **почему;** Он ушёл и не сказал **куда;** Он обещал скоро вернуться, но не уточнил **когда;** Мать определяла температуру ребёнка губами: приложит их ко лбу и сразу определит **сколько;** Кто-то подал больному чашку воды, он даже не взглянул **кто;** Я не скажу **какое,** я говорю — большое несчастье.*

Я совсем недавно [спрашивал](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/461228?noredirect=1) про этот же случай, когда есть союзное слово, но только с предлогом. Alex_ander считает, что и здесь запятая не нужна, мне его ответ нравится и хочется верить, что он прав.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь, так и знал, что есть какое-то правило!

Comment: На здоровье! ;) Какая-то ерунда с этими скобками: рядом с тройкой она была не видна, поэтому пришлось обе цифры жирным выделить — так всё видно стало почему-то.